# PHP flock() - what's under the hood?

Tags: php, flock

After wrestling with PHP source for a half an hour, I gave up. :P The question is - what system call does the PHP flock() function call boil down to on a Gentoo Linux system? I'm having some issues with it (like *block-for-30-seconds-in-every-one-of-20-loop-iterations* kind of issues) and I would like to know why that is so.

Answer (score 3):

```
// example: $stream = fopen(FILE, 'rb') or die('???');
$md = stream_get_meta_data($stream);
echo $md['wrapper_type'];

flock($stream);
```

if this prints *plainfile* then the call to the php function flock() is handled by php_stdiop_set_option(...) which calls flock(). Depending on whether PHP was compiled with HAVE_FLOCK or not this may be the system call [flock()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/flock.2.html) or a function defined in flock_compat.c which utilizes [fcntl()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fcntl.2.html). On my gentoo system PHP was compiled with HAVE_FLOCK.

main/streams/plain_wrapper.c @ static int php_stdiop_set_option(...):

> ```
>        case PHP_STREAM_OPTION_LOCKING:
>             if (fd == -1) {
>                 return -1;
>             }
>
>             if ((zend_uintptr_t) ptrparam == PHP_STREAM_LOCK_SUPPORTED) {
>                 return 0;
>             }
>
>             if (!flock(fd, value)) {
>                 data->lock_flag = value;
>                 return 0;
>             } else {
>                 return -1;
>             }
>             break;
> ```

Answer (score 2):

http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fcntl.html

```
/etc/standard/flock_compat.c [line 66]    
ret = fcntl(fd, operation & LOCK_NB ? F_SETLK : F_SETLKW, &flck);
```

Comment: If this function is called or not depends on the compile time define HAVE_FLOCK

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're asking, PHP's `flock()` is a call to the Unix system function [**`flock()`**](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/flock/) on Gentoo. They have identical semantics.

Comment: I can't prove it because I'm not running a copy of PHP right now, but I believe so, yes. Why not try it out yourself with strace?

Comment: I have only FTP access to the server.

Comment: @Powerlord, You need to check the compiler settings/flags too.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using it on a networked or mounted drive? I wouldn't be surprised if what you are experiencing is [deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock), and some of the [comments in the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php#82521) talk about that.

[The documentation for flock](https://www.php.net/flock).

Comment: Read carefully - Gentoo Linux here. But the full setup is a bit complicated so I just want to know what it calls underneath, so that I can put the full picture together myself.

Comment: And no, it's not a deadlock, that I'm sure of. But there are other things I'm suspecting.

Comment: Ahh, I just found out that the file is on an NFS mount. And the host box is also trying to flock() it (load balanced webservers, you see).